# React-native-webview vs Java WebView performance?

Tags: android-webview, react-native

I have a question that I think some other people can wonder.

We are porting a HTML audio app to Android and there are some realtime audio processing and heavy computing involved so the performance is very important.

The question : **is there any performance compromises (cpu/ram/fps) when using React-Native + React-native-webview comparing to using Java + Webview?**

I don't have knowledge about React-Native, please excuse my ignorance :)

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please refer https://medium.com/mop-developers/mobile-app-development-react-native-vs-native-ios-android-49c5c168045b